# Apache Commons Validator and JUnit

Tags: java, exception, junit

I'm using Apache Commons Validator to validate input within a builder pattern.

Once build() is called on the builder, the variables are checked using methods such as:

```
Validate.notNull(oranges, "Oranges was not set.");
```

When testing my code, I can see that when I do not set oranges, I do indeed get the message "Oranges was not set". However, the exception that is thrown is still a NullPointerException.

In my unit tests, I want to check that the validator is used and a message is output, but clearly using:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
```

will pass regardless of whether the Validator is used or a message is set.

Is there a way I can check that the validator is used and the message is set in JUnit? If not, is there a library that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Was the use of NullPointerException intentional or just a side-effect from the Commons Validator code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only check the external behaviour of your code. In your case this is: it throws a `NullPointerException` with the appropriate message.

There are different ways for testing exceptions (see [JUnit Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing)). You can always use JUnit's [ExpectedException rule](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html)

```
public class YourTest {
  @Rule
  public final ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

  @Test
  public void test() {
    ...
    thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("Oranges was not set.");
    builder.build();
  }
}
```

With Java 8 you can use the method [exceptionThrownBy](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/fishbowl/apidocs/com/github/stefanbirkner/fishbowl/Fishbowl.html#exceptionThrownBy-com.github.stefanbirkner.fishbowl.Statement-) provided by the library [Fishbowl](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/fishbowl/index.html). It allows you to use [Arrange-Act-Assert pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert).

```
public class YourTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    ...
    Throwable exception = exceptionThrownBy(() -> builder.build());
    assertEquals(NullPointerException.class, exception.getClass());
    assertEquals("Oranges was not set.", exception.getMessage());
  }
}
```